# Can't get tweets with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to build a tweet scraper for my nlp project but i cant get tweets.

Here is codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time


query = 'mutluluk'
URL = 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + query + '&src=typed_query&f=live'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(URL)


wait.until(EC.title_contains(query + ' - Twitter Araması / Twitter'))
tweets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#tweet-text").text

print(tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

The page that is returned does not have the title you expect, your wait condition is too specific. If you change it to:

```
 wait.until(EC.title_contains(query)
```

or

```
wait.until(EC.title_contains(query + ' - Twitter)
```

you'll get a page of tweets. After that, I don't think you have the right CSS selector, because it finds no matching element, so you need to further investigate the page contents with the developer tools.

Comment: actually my condition is right and it did not work after i made comment this line. I tried other selector/id/xpath and i could not get tweets

Answer (score 0):

1. You can wait until the elements you are searching for are present, rather than waiting explicitly for a text in the page title.
2. Your css selector is too poor for those types of websites, I recommend using XPATH, because big websites generally randomize the classes of the most elements in the DOM, so parsing the document will not be easy for beginners.

Use this snippet and you will get the text of your elements :

```
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
(By.XPATH, "//main//article")))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
```

Comment: actually i read that xpath is the most insecure.

Comment: Yes, maybe! 
But, I cannot believe that a web developer can put two "main" tags on the same page.

Comment: Maybe web devs not use 2 main tags, but xpath may change in any refactor or new version